# Почему progress bar(Vaadin) не обновляется динамически при выполнении операции удаления из DB?

Tags: java, ui, progress-bar, vaadin

Файл загружается успешно. Метод deleteMsisdns - который выполняется асинхронно, отвечает за выполнение sql скрипта на удаление данных. Метод getDeletedCount - отвечает за мониторинг удаленных данных, в нем вычисляется отношение удаленных данных к общему кол-ву, которое необходимо удалить и это значение передается методу processingUpdated, в котором должно происходить обновление progress bar. По логам приложения в него на каждой итерации поступает новое значение, но обновление progress bar не происходит. В чем может быть причина?

```
public class ProfilesDeletionPage extends AbstractIntfPage {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfilesDeletionPage.class);

    static final String[] HEADERS = {"MSISDN"};

    Label statusLabel;

    int all = 0;
    Long sequenceId;
    Long totalCountToDelete;

    Button submitButton;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    File tempFile;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    @Autowired
    MicaCommonDaoImpl dao;

    public ProfilesDeletionPage() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        boolean btnEnabled = user.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Roles.APPLICATION_ADMIN.name()));
        if (!btnEnabled) {
            showNotification("Only admin is allowed to delete msisdns", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        Upload uploadCSV = new Upload("Upload csv here", null);
        final CsvReceiver receiver = new CsvReceiver();
        uploadCSV.setReceiver(receiver);
        final UploadListener listener = new UploadListener();
        uploadCSV.addFinishedListener(listener);
        progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setVisible(false);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        statusLabel = new Label();

        submitButton = new Button("Delete uploaded msisdns");
        submitButton.setEnabled(false);
        submitButton.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) event -> {
            final AsyncDeletionProcessService deletionService = app.getBean(AsyncDeletionProcessService.class);
            progressBar.setCaption("Processing...");
            progressBar.setVisible(true);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            deletionService.deleteMsisdns(sequenceId, user.getId(), user.getLogin());
            deletionService.getDeletedCount(totalCountToDelete, this::processingUpdated, this::processingSucceeded);
        });


        HorizontalLayout horLay = new HorizontalLayout();
        horLay.setSpacing(true);
        horLay.addComponents(submitButton);
        horLay.setComponentAlignment(submitButton, Alignment.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        layout.setSpacing(true);
        layout.addComponents(uploadCSV, statusLabel, progressBar, horLay);
    }

    public void processingUpdated(Float progress) {
        log.info("processingUpdated");
        UI.getCurrent().access(() -> progressBar.setValue(progress));
    }

    public void processingSucceeded() {
        log.info("processingUpdated");
        UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
            progressBar.setVisible(false);
            Notification.show("Done!");
        });
    }

    class CsvReceiver implements Upload.Receiver {

        @Override
        public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
            log.info("profiles deletion file has been received");
            all = 0;
            submitButton.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".csv");
                fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return fos;
        }
    }

    class UploadListener implements Upload.FinishedListener {

        @Override
        public void uploadFinished(Upload.FinishedEvent event) {
            log.info("finish upload");
            List<String> msisdnList = Lists.newArrayList();

            try {
                log.info("we are before reading the file");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                log.info("we are after reading the file");

                //check headers
                if (line == null || !headersAreCorrect(line)){
                    Notification notification = new Notification("Wrong file (wrong csv headers)", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
                    notification.setDelayMsec(4000);
                    notification.setPosition(Position.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                    notification.show(Page.getCurrent());
                    return;
                }

                //add msisdns to the list
                log.info(all + " " + line);
                while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    all++;
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    log.info(all + " " + line);
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
                        msisdnList.add(line.trim());
                    }
                }
                log.info("msisdnList: " + msisdnList);
                all--;
                reader.close();

                sequenceId = dao.insertMsisdnsInTempTable(event.getFilename(), user.getLogin(), "NEW", msisdnList);
                totalCountToDelete = dao.getTotalCountToDelete();
                log.info("sequenceId {}, OK, totalCountToDelete {} ", sequenceId, totalCountToDelete);
                statusLabel.setValue("File loading success.");
                submitButton.setEnabled(true);

            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean headersAreCorrect(String line) {
        String[] headers = line.split(",");
        return Arrays.equals(HEADERS, headers);
    }
}

@Service(value = "asyncDeletionProcessService")
public class AsyncDeletionProcessService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncDeletionProcessService.class);

    @Autowired
    MicaCommonDaoImpl dao;

    @Autowired
    CommonDao commonDao;

    Long deletedCount = 0L;
    Long remainingCount;

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor asyncDeletionProcessExecutor;

    public void deleteMsisdns(Long sequenceId, Long id, String login) {
      log.info("we are in deleteMsisdns method in AsyncDeletionProcessService class");
        Runnable r = () -> {
            int res = dao.deleteMsisdns();
            log.info("res {}", res);

            if (res > 0) {
                String text = String.format("sequenceId %d, admin %d %s", sequenceId, id, login);
                log.info(text);
                commonDao.writeLog(new LogMessage(Facility.DELETE_CUSTOMERS, null, text, "new"));
                dao.updateMsisdnBatchToDelete(sequenceId, "NEW", "OK");
            } else {
                log.info("Deletion failed");
            }
        };
        asyncDeletionProcessExecutor.execute(r);
    }

    public void getDeletedCount(Long totalCountToDelete, Consumer<Float> progressListener, Runnable succeededListener) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            while(deletedCount < totalCountToDelete) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Query the temporary table to get the count of remaining records
                remainingCount = dao.getRemainingMsisdnCount();
                deletedCount = totalCountToDelete - remainingCount;
                float progress = (float)deletedCount/totalCountToDelete;
                log.info("progress {}", progress);
                progressListener.accept(progress);
                log.info("remainingCount {}, deletedCount {}", remainingCount, deletedCount);
            }
            succeededListener.run();
        };
        asyncDeletionProcessExecutor.execute(r);
    }
}
```